# Is there a performance issue with using very large background-position offsets?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm building a progress bar control, and I'm working on the case where it doesn't actually show progress, but just spinning indicator of "something is happening". The design I have for it is basically alternating diagonal stripes, essentially a barber pole kinda like this, but "spinning":

[image: A barber pole progress bar]

With the hopes of offloading as much as I can to the rendering engine, I want to use CSS transitions for this. **Supporting old browsers is not a concern for me.**

So, my first idea was to basically do this:

```
.barber-pole {
    background-image: url(repeating-slice.png);

    /* set a very long (one hour!) transition on the background-position */
    transition: background-position 3600s linear 0s;
}
```

... and then, when it gets rendered to the screen, use Javascript to essentially do this:

```
myBarberPole.style.backgroundPosition = '-1000000px 0';
```

Are there any performance issues about:

1. Transitioning for that long
2. Having `background-position: -1000000px 0` ?

Alternatively, do you have a better solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2ZZu/ - I tested quickly with the latest version of Chrome dev, and Firefox 4, and it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there could be any performance issues. It's not because you use *big* numbers that they use more CPU or memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of 'chaining' transitions to themselves (as far as I know there is no pure-CSS way of telling when the transition has finished) this could be a good solution, but as Justin says it requires a massive image! Is there any problem with using a good old-fashioned animated GIF?

Comment: re: the animated gif thing, the style is *similar* to the image I showed, but the striping is actually just a lightened tone of the underlying background-color, via use of a semi-transparent png. I need to be able to change the color underneath dynamically, so I need to stick with pngs.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Then I say go for it - if you are confident the download will never take more than 1 hour, I don't see a problem with it!