# Indeterminate progress bar in HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, progress-bar

I would like to create an **indeterminate HTML+CSS progress bar** so it looks like the one on Vista:

[image: Vista indeterminate progress bar]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC121865.png))</sub>

I would like to:

1. horizontally adjust it to progress bar width (minimum and maximum width may be defined)
2. don't use Javascript but rather just animated GIF
3. having only one moving indicator on the whole width

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski: All of them. ;) FF (latest), CH (latest) and IE (8+)

Comment: Slightly related, but not too much: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/

Comment: @ANeves: Why don't you put this **extremely clever comment** into an answer because this is the best solution to my problem and if you provide a JSFiddle along with it with two different width progress bars with the same image being animated would be best P.S. This actually reminds me of the marquee that we extensively abused back in the beginning of the nineties. :)

Comment: ... because I do not think it is a good approach, unless you marquee a static image - which would maybe make progressive enhancement harder. But sure, let's give it a try. And yeah, this marquee thing gives me the shivers.

Comment: Actually, it completely *does not apply because we are not talking about content* **overflowing**: `(...)CSS allows the designer to specify whether and how the overflow is displayed. One way, available on certain devices, is the “marquee” effect`. Best luck on your quest.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344621/is-there-a-performance-issue-with-using-very-large-background-position-offsets

Comment: @ANeves: I dismissed the marquee solution because I've seen it having bugs when you resize window. So it's either GIF, Javascript or CSS3 transition, which is not ok, since I have to support IE8 which doesn't support transitions yet...

Comment: @thirtydot very clever and nice but IE8 doesn't support css3 transitions.

Comment: wait, this was in 2011? wow!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## NO, NO, NO! It is possible

Using CSS `overflow: hidden` and `keyframe`, it can be possible.

For the keyframe, I used from `left:-120px`(width of the glowing object) to `left:100%`

<s>The structure I used:</s>

```
<div class="loader">
<div class="loader-bg left"></div>
<div class="loader-bg right"></div>
<div class="greenlight"></div>
<div class="gloss"></div>
<div class="glow"></div>
</div>
```

The updated, compact structure using `:before` and `:after`:

```
<div class="loader7">
    <span></span>
    <div class="greenlight"></div>
</div>
```

The gradient, masking, glowing and all the effects cost an expensive structure. If anyone has a better idea, please let me know.

<s>At this date, webkit only solution(the ellipse mask for the glow):</s>

**Added SVG mask for Firefox and other browsers that do not support `-webkit-mask-image`:** http://jsfiddle.net/danvim/8M24k/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. css - width:100%
2. no Javascript means you will have to do it with html5 which is a bit trickier. An animated GIF would work only if you decide to make the bar fixed-width (otherwise the gif will be skewed)
3. to move it: javascript or html5

The easiest way: javascript (like it or not... ;) )

Comment: CSS3 can move the green glow, please see my answer

Comment: @DanielCheung thanks for the update. Stuff evolves, it's cool that you took the time to update with a more modern answer.

Answer (score 0):

### GIF-only solution

Vista's indeterminate progress bar doesn't loop right after it goes off on the right...
So I could create a wide enough GIF image and when progress bar would be narrow it would take longer for it to loop and when it'd be wider it loops again sonner. :)

Time of each repeat is the same in both cases but in narrow bar it takes less to get to the end than on the wider ones.